# Downloaded png files not readable

Tags: android, image, png

I've downloaded a number of png files via a service, and now I'm trying to use them. They go onto the user's SD card. I've verified that each of the files is on the card. But when I try to set any of them as an ImageView, I get blank space.

So, then I went to see that the files were intact by just manually trying to display them on the phone using the phone's picture viewer. None of the files will open. What I would like to know is if I'm missing any steps after downloading the files that need to occur to make them viewable as png files (or bitmap files). Here is the code in my service that I use to download the files:

```
public class DownloadPicture extends IntentService {

    private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
    public static final String FILENAME = "filename";
    public static final String FILEPATH = "filepath";
    public static final String RESULT = "result";
    public static final String NOTIFICATION "com.mydomain.myapp.MyBroadcastReceiver";

    public DownloadPicture() {
        super("DownloadPicture");
    }

    public DownloadPicture(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        String fileName = intent.getStringExtra(FILENAME);
        String urlPath = this.getResources().getString(R.string.imagesURL) + fileName;
        System.err.println("starting download of: " + fileName);
        System.err.println(urlPath);
        File output = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
        if (output.exists()) {output.delete();}

        InputStream stream = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
          URL url = new URL(urlPath);
          stream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
          InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
          fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());
          int next = -1;
          while ((next = reader.read()) != -1) {
            fos.write(next);
          }

          //Maybe I need to do something else here????

          // Successful finished
          result = Activity.RESULT_OK;

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          if (stream != null) {
            try {
              stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
          if (fos != null) {
            try {
              fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }

        publishResults(output.getName(), output.getAbsolutePath(), result);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code appears to be correct. Are you sure urlPath point to a png file? Have you tried to download it using a browser?

Comment: Yes to both questions. Also, when I navigate directly to the SD card using my phone's file manager app, it has the extension .png.

Comment: Try downloading in your PC and then compare with the file downloaded in your device. There may be a connection problem and the file may be corrupted. And I think it won't hurt, but try read the input stream and write to the output stream with a buffer of a few bytes instead of one byte at a time, and try to flush before closing the output stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `InputStreamReader` it will transform byte stream to character streams.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html

In your case images must remain byte streams so you can just use the `InputStream` returned by the `URL` object:

```
while ((next = stream.read()) != -1) {
    fos.write(next);
}
```